# Details behind Geographic Jurisdictions for IRS Form 2555

Tags: irs, housing, japan, income-tax

For the Housing Exclusion and/or Deduction, Line 29b limit on the maximum deduction - How can one establish a level of confidence in the geographic borders drawn up by the IRS?

```
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/i2555--2015.pdf
```

An example here is Tokyo, Japan which has both Tokyo-To, which stretches all the way to the suburbs and Tokyo, which is not specified. Tokyo has a much higher daily rate - which is likely the core of Tokyo-To (Yamanote loop). Is there any better reference out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, I would call or visit the IRS. 
In this specific case, I would guess Tokyo refers to the official prefecture and tokyo-to is the metropolitan area around it.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I hope there are ways to find more authoritative sources without calling them...

Comment: I called the IRS - they are going to get back to me within 2 weeks to clarify the boundaries..

Answer (score 0):

I wholeheartedly disagree with Bishop. Tokyo-to in Japanese means the prefecture ("to" means prefecture specific to the capital) of Tokyo which includes the 23 central wards("ku") and the towns and villages ("shi", "cho", "son") on the western side of the prefecture. Without a clearer explanation or map from the IRS, what THEY mean by just Tokyo is speculation.